# C# Equivalent of Python's urlsafe_b64encode

Tags: c#, python, base64

I am trying to build an ASP.NET MVC application, which will use [Thumbor](https://github.com/globocom/thumbor) as a photo resizing backend, but have been running into problems with the security. Thumbor uses a SHA1 HMAC hash as a security system, which is based on the URL. So, the URL may look like:

```
http://thumbor-server/1234567890123456789012345678/300x200/smart/path/to/image.jpg
```

1234567890123456789012345678 being the hmac made up of a secret key and the 300...image.jpg section...

anyway, i can create the HMAC value alright, or at least i think i can, but when generating the URL, Thumbor sugests using the urlsafe_base64encode function from Python. I have tried System.Convert.ToBase64String, but thats not working, and url encoding the string does not work either. By "not working", i mean Thumbor is telling me the URL is malformed. There is not much to go by...

So, is there an equivalent? and if not, how would one go about generating a string the way it does?

Comment: `but thats not working` is not a good description of the problem - what's not working? And `ToBase64String` _is_ the way to do this.

Comment: Dont know if you already converted you string, but you should use ToBase64String like this: `string result = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("input"));`

Comment: @oded sorry mate, will tweak the question to explain whats not working...

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls yea, thats the way i am doing it. mind you, the Base64 string is not URL encoded.

Comment: Are you sure you are generating the Hash correctly ? Did you look at the HMAC class in .NET (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmac.aspx)?

Comment: @prthrokz yea, the hash is correct. when i was passing it in to the URL, it was not correctly formatted for URLs. after making the fix in my answer, it works perfectly...

Comment: @TiernanO Glad to know it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to get this working, by taking the Base64 string and replacing the `+` char with `-` and the `/` char with a `_`. This seems to be the way that Python is doing its [`urlsafe_b64encode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64encode)